# Silverlight / server folder permissions

Tags: silverlight, permissions, directory, file-permissions

My Silverlight web site is supposed to let the client download a zip file. The zip contains two pdf files that are copied to a temp folder, plus a third pdf file created using crystal reports. On debug in my computer this is working perfectly. However, I've just published the project on a remote server and I can't download the file.

I don't know if the problem is with silverlight or the server, since I wasn't the one that configured it. When I run fiddler, it throws an 'Access to folder is denied' error.

Both me and the server Administrator already set permissions to write and read from that folder to every account of the server, and still does not work.

Can anyone help with this, I can't seem to figure if the problem is with the server or silverlight. The server is running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.

Thanks

Comment: where's that folder? is it in `ClientBin`? Are you sure the path is configured correctly, and/or relative and not hardcoded for your machine? How do you let the user download that file? Via Silverlight Hyperlinkbutton? Does it go through an .aspx page or handler?

Comment: The folder is on root of server (c:\), and the path is configured on the web.config file. The download goes through a handler on a WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it has nothing to do with Silverlight.

The IIS worker process must have the rights to access this folder (mostly it's a group called `{MachineName}\IIS_IUSRS`).

If you're using Single Sign On/Impersonation, then the actual user as currently authenticated by the Network's (Windows) Domain Controller has to have access rights to that folder, which is not a recommended security architecture.

Comment: I know that it's not the a recommended approach. It was decided to do it like this due to haste on this project, which is on a stand-by since I can't seem to download the file.